# Как добавить результат выражения в список

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

```
import re
some = list()
hand = open('regex.txt')
for line in hand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    y = re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
    for piece in y:
        some.append[piece]
print(some)
```

Код выше бросает ошибку, суть кода парсить все числа из файла и сложить в один список.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, в таких случаях нужно приводить текст сообщения об ошибке.

Во-вторых, ошибка у вас здесь:

```
some.append[piece]
```

скобки здесь должны быть круглыми, а не квадратными.

Comment: Ну как бы на этом ошибка и устранилась)Спасибо большое, Александр)

Comment: @Huzkuy, "Спасибо большое" = клик на галочку у ответа.